# CSS for left and right align of the first line, with wrapped lines right aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a bar's menu and can't quite get the CSS to do what I want. I'd like the drink name to be left aligned and the description to be right aligned, with any wrapped lines also right aligned. (Let's stipulate that the drink name will never be more than one line.)

This is what I have so far (also at http://jsfiddle.net/H96XQ/)

CSS:

```
.alignleft {
   font-weight: 700;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   float: left;
   text-align:left;
   text-align
}
.alignright {
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: italic;
   float: right;
   text-align:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="textbox">
   <p class="alignleft">Old Fashioned</p>
   <p class="alignright">Bulleit Bourbon, Raw Sugar, Luxardo Maraschino Cherries, Soda, Orange</p>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <p class="alignright">Jameson Irish Whiskey, Coffee</p>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

The Irish Coffee line looks like I want. But if the combined left- and right- text is too wide for one line, it doesn't wrap the way I want - the description gets a line of its own.

The following does what I want, but only because I'm using two "alignright" instances in a row and figuring out where the wrap happens myself. And so every time we change the menu, I'd have to do it line by line and ... ugh.

```
<div id="textbox">
   <p class="alignleft">Old Fashioned</p>
   <p class="alignright">Bulleit Bourbon, Raw Sugar,</p>
   <p class="alignright"> Luxardo Maraschino Cherries, Soda, Orange</p>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <p class="alignleft">Irish Coffee</p>
   <p class="alignright">Jameson Irish Whiskey, Coffee</p>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eJD9E/1/)

HTML

```
<p>What I want:</p>
<div id="textbox">
        <h3>Old Fashioned</h3>
        <p >Bulleit Bourbon, Raw Sugar, Luxardo Maraschino Cherries, Soda, Orange</p>
        <h3>O'Henry</h3>
        <p>Buffalo Trace Bourbon, Benedictine, Liqueur, Fever Tree Ginger Beer</p>
        <h3>Hemingway</h3>
        <p>Aged White Rum, Fresh Lime &amp;
         Grapefruit Juice, Maraschino Liqueur, Lucardo Maraschino Cherries</p>
        <h3>Irish Coffee</h3>
        <p>Jameson Irish Whiskey, Coffee</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#textbox {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
#textbox h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight: 700px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
}
#textbox p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #333;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: @Dave No problem, please consider a marked solved if you don't have any other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

just add `display:inline;` for alignleft and alignright classes [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H96XQ/4/)